# Indoor navigation system without google maps

Tags: android, gps, android-wifi, indoor-positioning-system

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction, I am trying to make an indoor navigation system. I have the floorplans but I can't do it with google maps and I am lost on how I would do such a thing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you planning for the positioning technology? Getting the accurate position indoors is actually more complex than displaying the floor plan.

Comment: I was thinking of using fusedlocation api and then if later on down the line if i find that that isn't precise enough then change that or if it is to demanding on power then also change it or try to make less demanding if possible. I can get the floor plan on my phone but by just displaying the pdf but other than that i am lost on how to make it so the app doesn't tell you to walk through floors etc.

Comment: Unless you are at one of the major locations included in he Google Indoor Maps programme, you will be disappointed with the results. I would recommend ordering some Bluetooth beacons and checking out some tutorials, e.g. https://proximi.io/accurate-indoor-positioning-bluetooth-beacons/ (Disclaimer: I am from Proximi.io).  There's a lot of different aspects to what you are trying to solve - indoor positioning, wayfinding, map visualization. It's not an easy task.